# Deploying vhd from blob to Azure

Tags: linux, azure, vhd, watchguard, blob-storage

- We have some troubles in migrating VM(Linux) from local HyperV on Win 10 to Azure Cloud.
- We got a  linux vhd - deploy it on HyperV - then save as static and upload to blob storade in Azure.
- Based on that - we make a new VM but it fails to start.

We got

```
kernel panic - not syncing : VFS : Unable to mount root fs on unknown-block(8,18)
CPU: 1 PID: 1 Comm: swapper/0 Not tainted 3.12.19-rt30 #1
…
Rebooting in 30 sec.
```

VHD is a WatchGuard firewall - deployed from official sources' vhd.
Watch guard Firebox Cloud doesn't suite to client's needs.

Thanks for any help!!

Comment: How do you create a new VM from the VHD file you uploaded to Azure Storage?

Comment: was following this post
https://blogs.infosupport.com/creating-a-vm-in-azure-based-on-an-uploaded-vhd/

Comment: I do the test and the steps are all right. So what is your OS type and version?

Comment: @KonstantinB. have you been able to locally boot a VM from the VHD you made?  I'm wondering if it's an issue with the VHD as opposed to an issue with the cloud resource you're spinning up.

Comment: @CharlesXu-MSFT if you are asking about OS on the VHD - it's WatchGuard FireboxV Hyper-V Fireware v12.1. It has it own OS based on Linux.

Comment: @user9975441 Of course. First Watchguard was deployed on local Win10 with Hyper-V. Then VHD was converted to static. And after i saw that VM with WG was booted successfully,  i can interact with it console, web UI and can connect to the WG whith special software for managing it - it's VHD was uploaded to Azure for further action.

Comment: @KonstantinB Maybe you can follow this link:[Kernel panic - not syncing: VFS: Unable to mount root fs on unknown-block(8,1)](https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-hardware-18/kernel-panic-not-syncing-vfs-unable-to-mount-root-fs-on-unknown-block-8-1-a-4175432147/). It's an error similar to yours. And you can recreate the VM with VHD file you uploaded so that you can make sure where the problem actually is.

Comment: @CharlesXu-MSFT Thanks for help but i think probably i wil not get root access to the WatchGuard OS engine to modify it...
Perhaps that trouble caused by latest MicroSoft security update, because six months ago the similar case with WG was successfully implemented

Comment: @KonstantinB I'm glad to hear that. Maybe there is something we don't know. If you get the real reason, please me know.